# iOS cocoapods always show " dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target."

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Last time, I am using ios 6. I have changed my minimum deployment target in project setting and cocoapod file.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

I already clear cache like this.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods; rm -rf Pods; rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*; pod deintegrate; pod setup; pod install;
```

But, why I always get this error ? How shall I do?

> Specs satisfying the `Realm (~> 1.0)` dependency were found, but they
>   required a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: Have you changed in your Project?

Comment: yes. I changed in my project.

Comment: Hi @KhantThuLinn
Did you finally find a solution for it?
I've read that Realm 1.0.0 had iOS 7.0 so I'm not sure about why you could get it.
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/b/a/7/Realm/1.0.0/Realm.podspec.json#L56
I've fixed it by changing the deployment target of my project